# Could not set the selected property JQuery. JQuery Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code will not work for me in ie6 but unsurprisingly, it does work in every other browser:

$('#myDropdown').val('value');

I have no idea why this is happening.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Lets see your dropdown markup. Does each option have a `value` attribute specified?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to do something like

```
$("#myDropdown > option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
$("#myDropdown > option[value='value']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to set the innerHTML of the select.

I came up with the following extension method that has a special routine for IE6:

```
$.fn.setDropDownValue = function(valueToSet) {
    if ((!this[0].options) || (this[0].options.length == 0))
        return;

    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6.0) {
        var open = '<OPTION value=\'';
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < this[0].options.length; i++) {
            var opt = $(this[0].options[i]);
            html += open + $(opt).val() + '\'';
            if (opt.val() == valueToSet) {
                html += ' selected';
            }
            html += '>' + opt.html() + '</OPTION>';
        }
        $(this).html(html);
    } else {
        this.val(valueToSet);
    }
};
```

Comment: adding to this in IE6 after setting the value the dropdown shrinks. so we can add $(this).css('width','auto'); The issue happens when the dropdown options have been created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known IE 6 bug.  The work around is to do something like:

```
options[1].setAttribute('selected', true)
```

or something that delays it like:

```
setTimeout("$('#myDropdown').val('" + value + "')",1);
```

or just wrap it in a try / catch block and ignore the exception - the value still gets set in IE6.

Comment: just 2 cents: http://protopl.us/2010/04/14/jquery-ie6-could-not-set-the-selected-property-unspecified-error/